# Unable to connect to store when configuring kvstore via ssl

Tags: ssl, oracle-nosql

I tried creating a ssl configuration for my kvstore, I configure the store and create a user root , however whenever I try to connect to a store , I get the following error :

```
- kv-> connect store -name OracleNoSqlSecurityTests -security /home/impadmin/oracle/client.txt
Error handling command connect store -name OracleNoSqlSecurityTests -security /home/impadmin/oracle/client.txt: Cannot connect to OracleNoSqlSecurityTests at localhost:5000
```

When I restart the kvstore server and trie to create user root again I get the following :

```
kv-> plan create-user -name root -admin -wait
Enter the new password: 
Re-enter the new password: 
This command can't be used until the Admin is configured.
```

Any clue what is going on here ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it is just a matter of wrong port.

Have you tried without SSL ? In case it helps, this is how I use to connect to kvstore:

```
java -jar $KVHOME/lib/kvstore.jar kvlite -root $KVROOT -host localhost &
java -jar $KVHOME/lib/kvstore.jar runadmin -port 5000 -host localhost
kv-> connect store -host localhost -port 5000 -name kvstore ;
```